# Codeigniter not retrieving session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies

i have a codeigniter( version 2.2.6 ) app in localhost.

i'm trying to login user.

i use database to store sessions.

session config in config.php

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'myapp';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'myapp_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

and it works, it is saves userdata in database

```
$userdata = array(
'user_id'  => $result['id'],
'username'  => $result['username'],
'is_admin' => $result['is_admin'],
'logged_in' => TRUE
);
$this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
```

**BUT, when i try to retrieve data it gives me NULL;**

```
$this->session->userdata('username');
```

any ideas?

```
EDIT:
```

request for: var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());

```
array(4) {
  ["session_id"]=>
  string(32) "767eab3e9539d0bdc29faeb48ad86919"
  ["ip_address"]=>
  string(9) "127.0.0.1"
  ["user_agent"]=>
  string(110) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"
  ["last_activity"]=>
  int(1455306997)
}
```

Comment: In which files did you used `$this->session>userdata` and `$this->session->set_userdata` ?

Comment: please, show more debug information such as `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata())`

Comment: im setting data and retrievin in controller file

Comment: Don't use CI 2.x, it's no longer supported.

Comment: try `$this->session->set_userdata('userdata', $userdata);`

Comment: @Narf  changing version is not solution for this problem.

Comment: @DiegoMariani  not works.

Comment: @GiaNebieridze I didn't say that it was, although I do believe it probably is in your case.

Comment: Are you setting and retrieving session data in the same request or two different requests?

Comment: Did you put a value for encryption key in application/config.php ?

Comment: oh and Narf is a primary contributor to codeigniter which is why he is urging you to upgrade :-)

Comment: thank you all guys. problem was database driver. used pdo wich not worked. changed to mysql and now works!